# The way of running karate tests in parallel - question

Tags: java, karate

I have a question:) How does it work karate if it comes to parallel execution?
We use karate in specific way where under the hood we hava a bunch of java code. I'm curious if variables declared as ThreadLocal in our java code is really thread save? 
Is each test run in separate thread or there is another way of running test simultaneously?
The problem we faced is that it looks like a least two of running tests have access to ThreadLocal variable which should be isolated from each other. 
Could you explain?

Comment: Please don't request someone to answer this question. Remove that part.

Comment: Ok, done. Thanks for advice

Comment: Good job with trying to become better :) Hope you get your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `ThreadLocal` you are on your own :) The short answer is Karate will create a thread-pool for `Scenario` execution, and each `Scenario` can go onto any of these threads. Maybe you need to read [this section](https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallelfalse) on how you can force some `Scenario`-s to run in sequence - but you may still have problems if the ones that ran first do not "clean up".

EDIT: I also think it should NOT be possible for 2 Scenarios to be on the same thread at the *same time* and if you are seeing this - it is a bug, please help us replicate it (see last line of my answer).

Karate's multi threading is battle-tested and we would not be able to claim that you can do the [Gatling integration](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/845#issuecomment-516402180) if this was not the case. Maybe you should just trust Karate for doing all the heavy lifting you need ? For example look at "hooks": https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks

And of course, if you really do think there's an issue, follow this process please: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: FYI We've investigated problem described above and it looks like there was problem on our side. BTW we confirmed that any test(any thread) have its own instances of ThreadLocal variable what was expected from the beginning.